# Does the current supplied to the load doubles when the voltage is doubled

Tags: voltage, current

Let's say that the load is connected to a 12V battery consumes 3A current. When the 12V battery is replaced with 24V battery causes 6A current flow for the same load.

I'm just trying to understand if the load consumes only the required amps from the source battery regardless of the voltage of the battery or does the change in voltage has direct impact on current flowing through the load

Comment: 'the required amps' is a bit of a misinterpretation; if the load is supplied with a voltage that is above the rated value then it will draw too much current. The resistance of the load and the supply voltage determine the current, and this is governed by Ohm's law: \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$, so doubling the voltage, doubles the current.

Comment: @Chu Does that means the electronic devices are made in consideration with the grid volt system (120/240 V etc). and if the devices made for 240V system is connected to 120V system then it will not be able to draw much current?

Comment: Electronic devices are not connected directly to an AC power source - the AC is changed to DC at the required voltage, and with consideration of the current demands of the device. The circuit that does the conversion from AC to DC is designed to work with a given supply voltage, so it will probably not work as desired at a lower or higher voltage source.

Comment: @Chu That means the electronic devices made to operate on both (120V/240V) systems has a conversion ckt which can handle both incoming voltages and outputs to a constant DC voltage. right?

Comment: @Chu not all electronic components are resistors; those that are not resistors don’t obey the Ohm’s law. Moreover, PSUs are electronic devices that are connected directly to an AC power source.

Comment: @user2233709 the OP was specifically about loads, and my comment about electronic devices related to this and not to electronic components in the DC power source. There are some negative resistance configurations out there. 'Those that are not resistors don't obey Ohm's law' is rather a sweeping statement. Resistance is exhibited by components other than resistors. I don't think I used the word 'resistor' in my comments.

Comment: @chu "The resistance of the load and the supply voltage determine the current, and this is governed by Ohm's law: I=VR, **so doubling the voltage, doubles the current**." The emphasized statement is true only if the load is linear, even if you can define a point resistance for non-linear loads (i.e. non-linear resistance), as the ratio V/I.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati, it was a comment, not an answer. I guess I could have said 'for ideal components' or something, but judging by the wording, the OP was looking the LTI answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what the load is.

If the load is a resistor with good stability, and adequate power handling for the higher supply, then yes, at twice the voltage it will draw twice the current.

For other loads, the situation is more complicated.

If a resistor has a positive temperature coefficient, like a filament lamp, then it will take less than twice the current at twice the voltage, as it heats up and increases resistance.

If its power handling is only good for the lower supply, it may take twice the current briefly, then burn out and drop to zero.

More complicated loads, like a universal input voltage power brick, may take constant power when charging the laptop battery, so take twice the current at 120v that it takes at 240v.

Comment: *take half the current at 120v that it takes at 240v?* Do you mean *takes double current at 120v that it takes at 240v*

Comment: @VVK doh! Good catch, I'm glad someone's awake. Fixed.

Comment: `If the load is a resistor with good stability, and adequate power handling for the higher supply, then yes, at twice the voltage it will draw twice the current` assuming the ideal supply.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 No. Such a resistor fed with twice the voltage will draw twice the current. The quality of any power supply involved is irrelevant. It's outside the system under consideration, which is the resistor, and the voltage on its terminals. It could be an AC supply, and we're talking about instantaneous voltage and current. If I'd wanted the supply to be part of the system, I would have specified it, which would have cluttered the answer with irrelevancies.

Comment: @Neil_UK if it is the theoretical situation, the question should be closed as it is the Ohm equation, and it is a primary school problem